# The lights seem to dim when we plug anything into the bottom part of the outlet in the kitchen. Wondering why this could be happening?

Tags: electrical

When we plug anything into the bottom plug in on 1 particular outlet in our kitchen the lights seem to dim but this didn't happen when you plug anything into the top or any of the other outlets. Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Are the lights and outlets on the same circuit? Is what you're plugging in a high-power device (like a microwave), or does it happen with a small lamp as well? Do the lights dim and then return to their normal brightness or stay dim?

Comment: I'm not sure if they are on the same circuit or not. I don't think so though. The lights dim slightly and stay that way. It happens when I plug in like a mixer or can opener I never plug anything bigger than that in there.

Comment: I just asked my husband he said they are all on the same circuit and that they just flash off then come back sorry for the above.

Comment: Sounds like a bad connection, It is unusual that only the bottom outlet affects the lights unless one of the outlets are switched.

Answer (score 1):

First possibility, a bad receptacle or bad wiring connections to the receptacle. Deal with that fast -- it burns down houses.

Builders often use the cheap 60-cent receptacles, and they are also fond of using "back stab" connections to those receptacles which are terrible.  Replace with a $4-tier receptacle which has side screws or [screw-and-clamp](https://www.handymanhowto.com/electrical-outlets-side-wire-versus-back-wire/).

Comment: Ok thank you I will have my husband take a look at what you said.

Comment: I agree 100%. The extra cost of back and side outlets cost me several jobs over the years, but I have more than made up on those going back and upgrading the outlets to spec grade.